# TYPO3 Extbase - The configuration file "ext_emconf.php" seems to be invalid

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I try to upload my extension but I get `Please check your uploaded extension "my_download_plugin". The configuration file "ext_emconf.php" seems to be invalid.`
What is supposed to be wrong with this configuration file?

```
<?php

/***************************************************************
 * Extension Manager/Repository config file for ext: "my_download_plugin"
 *
 * Auto generated by Extension Builder 2017-01-30
 *
 * Manual updates:
 * Only the data in the array - anything else is removed by next write.
 * "version" and "dependencies" must not be touched!
 ***************************************************************/

$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array(
    'title' => 'my_download_plugin',
    'description' => 'Downloadlist for my Donwloadcenter',
    'category' => 'plugin',
    'author' => 'Edward Black',
    'author_email' => 'my.name@mycompany.de',
    'state' => 'beta',
    'createDirs' => '',
    'uploadfolder' => false,
    'clearCacheOnLoad' => false,
    'version' => '2.0.0',
    'constraints' => array(
        'depends' => array(
            'typo3' => '6.2.0-6.3.0',
            'static_info_tables' => '6.3.9'
        ),
        'conflicts' => array(),
        'suggests' => array()
    )
);
```

I was reading [the official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/DeclarationFile/Index.html) but could not find anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The TYPO3 version 6.3.0 does not exist. If you want to handle 6.2.x use `6.2.0-6.2.99`

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency to `static_info_tables` seems to be wrong, since you only have given the lower version number. Please add the dependency to `static_info_tables` like shown below:

`'static_info_tables' => '6.3.9-0.0.0'`

This will require a minimum version 6.3.9 of `static_info_tables` extension with no maximum version requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to set the version for "static_info_tables" to all for developing purposes.

Next you can add `"sjbr/static-info-tables" => "*"` to your composer.json.

Install the new dependency.

Now take the package version from the composer.lock-file and add it to your composer.json and now u can fix the version in your ext_emconf.php